# How to post form data in asp.net using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to post form data of asp.net using ajax. and want to receive that data on another page as form array.

this is want I am doing now 
Default2.aspx

```
 $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default3.aspx",
                data:  $('#form1'),
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("Success");
                }
            });
        });
```

and on Default3.aspx

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int loop1;
        NameValueCollection coll;

        //Load Form variables into NameValueCollection variable.

        coll = Request.Form;
        // Get names of all forms into a string array.
        String[] arr1 = coll.AllKeys;
        for (   loop1 = 0; loop1 < arr1.Length; loop1++)
        {
            Response.Write("Form: " + arr1[loop1] + "<br>");
            Label1.Text = arr1[loop1];
        }

    }
```

Update : I am sending serialized object through ajax call . I want to that data in my asp.net code. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `serialize` method.

Since you are using a form you can let it control how to do the post:

```
var $frm = $('#form1');
$('input[type="submit]', $frm).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: $frm.attr('method'),
        url: $frm.attr('action'),
        data:  $frm.serialize(),
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Success");
        }
    });
});
```

Which can be refactored into a generic script that you can place in your masterpage:

```
<script type="text-javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.post-using-ajax').each(function() {
            var $frm = $(this);
            $frm.submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    type: $frm.attr('method'),
                    url: $frm.attr('action'),
                    data:  $frm.serialize(),
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert("Success");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Which let's you to transform all forms with the CSS class `post-using-ajax` into AJAX forms.

```
<form method="POST" action="someAction" class="post-using-ajax">
    <!-- all form items -->
</form>
```

Comment: @MurtazaHussain: What are you trying to say? Both parts of my example should work as you say. You might want to rephrase your question otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Check this once .
[Post data to other page using ajax](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_webforms_Post_Data_To_PageMethod.ashx)

Comment: not helping. I making ajax call and want to receive data on the request page. I want to know that how I can receive data..

Comment: Consider adding the important content of the link to your answer. The link you have now doesn't directly answer the question, and instead links only to a project.

Answer (score 0):

if there was few fields in your form, maybe you should use $.ajax like as :

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "default3.aspx",
                data: {name:"usename", sex:"male", age:"18"},
                dataType:"json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("Success");
                }
            });
```

i think this is the simplest way.